# Unicode hyphen causes error when building R documentation

Tags: r, latex, pdflatex, roxygen2

I'm trying to put together my first package for R, and I'm unable to generate the PDF for the documentation using `R CMD Rd2pdf`. The error I get is

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ‐ (U+2010)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

I don't really understand what's going on here, since it seems absurd that the hyphen symbol would naturally throw an error in building documentation for an R package. I'm using roxygen2 to build the package, and the main file is saved with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: usually they need a \ .. try `\u2010` instead?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: I found and fixed the problem. I had copied and pasted the title of one of my references, and it had a dash symbol that was not the same as the usual hyphen.

Comment: Good that you found a solution. It is still strange since (reasonably modern) LaTeX is capable of handling U+2010.